# How to create a clipping mask from an NSAttributedString?

Tags: macos, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I have an NSAttributedString which I would like to draw into a CGImage so that I can later draw the CGImage into an NSView. Here's what I have so far:

```
// Draw attributed string into NSImage
NSImage* cacheImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(w, h)];
[cacheImage lockFocus];
[attributedString drawWithRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height) options:0];
[cacheImage unlockFocus];

// Convert NSImage to CGImageRef
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(
    (CFDataRef)[cacheImage TIFFRepresentation], NULL);
CGImageRef img =  CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
```

I'm not using -[NSImage CGImageForProposedRect:context:hints] because my app must use the 10.5 sdk.

When I draw this into my NSView using CGContextDrawImage, it draws a transparent background around the text, causing whatever is behind the window to show through. I think I want to create a clipping mask, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your blend mode it set up as Copy instead of SourceOver. Take a look at [the CoreGraphics blend mode documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetBlendMode).